# constant function in complex analysis

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

So we just talked about the cauchy riemann equations and had the example $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow E$ where $E$ is the disk $E= \lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} : \mid z \mid \leq 1 \rbrace$ and f differentiable. Then $f$ has to be constant. But why?

However I do understand why $f$ has to be constant when $Re(f)$ or $Im(f)$ is constant with cauchy riemann equations.

Comment: This is called Liouville's theorem. I don't think it can be deduced directly from C-R equations.

Comment: Actually i do know about Liouvilles theorem. I tried to get behind this problem without it. We didnt get to know Liouvilles theorem yet.